# Как можно сделать чтобы действие совершалось только если предустановленное время было на 60 секунд меньше чем текущее время?

Tags: javascript, html

Как можно сделать чтобы действие совершалось только если время день-минуты-секунды было на 60 секунд меньше чем текущее время? То есть, если установлено время 16.17.18 (д-м-с), то чтобы div стал виден только если время будет на минуту больше (16.18.18). Время устанавливаться будет другим скриптом..
пробовал так:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var currDay = new Date();
var dayTime = currDay.getHours()+currDay.getMinutes()+currDay.getSeconds();
if (dayTime <= 1.1.1) {
 document.write("day");
} else {
 document.write("night");
}
</script>
```

но не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так

```
let currDay = new Date().getTime();
if (new Date().getTime() - currDay > 60000) {
document.write("day");
} else {
document.write("night");
}
```

Comment: Далее при надобности можно преобразовать в читаемый вид